# Premature end of script headers (perl+index.html)

Tags: perl, apache, cgi

Respected ppl ...

Im on openSUSE 12.2 and my Apache server is running fine ...

I copied the index.html which contains :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head><title>Program 7b</title></head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost/cgi-bin/7b.pl">
    Please Enter the Command :
    <input type="text" name="command" id="command" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And the perl file as follows :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "Content-type:text/html\n\n";
use CGI

$a = new CGI;
$comm = $a->param("command");
print "The Output of the entered command is:<br />";
system($comm);
```

Both files in the cgi-bin directory

But i get the error :

Premature end of script headers
On running localhost/cgi-bin/index.html in any browser ....

I have set the execution of perl files in the apache configuration ...

Kindly help with the problem ...

Regards
-SkyKOG

Comment: You have a very serious security hole in executing a param in a system call. What if someone enters `rm -rf /` as the command param? Also, you should always use `use strict; use warnings;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache is running index.html as a script, not simply displaying an HTML document.  Apache is probably configured to run anything in the cgi directory as a script.

Move the html file into another directory.

Comment: Yes this was the correct answer i am new to perl just started ..i had kept both files in the cgi-bin dir ... the code worked fine when i moved the html file to htdocs folder :) ...

Answer (score 0):

Try the following working code :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;
use CGI;

print "Content-type:text/html\n\n";

my $a = new CGI;
my $comm = $a->param("command");

print "The Output of the entered command is:<br />";
system($comm);
```

An advice : never forget `use strict; use warnings;` and declare variables with `my` or `our`.

Comment: This can't work because, at the very least, the `use CGI` call is missing a semicolon.

Comment: post edited accordingly. Tested ok on my server from index.html provided by OP.